# Выбор способа управления коммутатором

Tags: c#, router, .net, protocol

Собираюсь написать на C# программу для мониторинга коммутаторов (какие порты активны, включить/отключить заданный порт, работает ли кулер на коммутаторе и т.д.).

Как я понял, управление коммутаторами может осуществляться посредством протоколов SNMP, Telnet, SSH.

Так как раньше с подобными задачами не сталкивался, не знаю, какой лучше из них использовать.

Еще есть такой момент, что в .NET нет встроенной поддержки этих протоколов, и придётся юзать сторонние библиотеки, которые могут оказаться кривыми.

Хотелось бы услышать любые советы по этому поводу.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри в эту сторону: [ссылка](http://www.rebex.net/)

Довольно-таки стабильные и отлаженные либы. Конкретно тебе нужно: SSH Shell or Telnet Terminal emulation